# Will the IC mess up if the inputs that don't affect the output are disconnected?

Tags: integrated-circuit, impedance, output, input

Here's the situation. I'm trying to incorporate ANY decoder in the HC family to decode two bits. I'm also using the eagle autorouter. I decided to go with [74HC139](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT139.pdf) since its a dual decoder and the pin arrangement is convenient, BUT because I'm not using one of the decoders, I tied pins 13 through 16 to VCC to effectively disable the second decoder, but when routing on the PCB, tying adjacent pins together eliminates routing opportunities and its a major cause of my routing to not complete.

Many chips have an input that controls everything. In this case, the 74HC139 has a gate input G on pin 15 to fully control the output. If it is set to high, all output lines are high regardless of pins 13 and 14 (input bit 0 and 1). Because of this, I begin to think I can just tie pin 15 and 16 together (make G high) and then leave pin 13 and 14 open.

Is this acceptable for an HC series chip or will bad things happen (even though the output is exactly the same regardless of the level of pin 13 and 14)?

Comment: Never leave inputs floating unless the datasheet specifically says it is OK to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Bad things happen with HCMOS logic if you allow any input pin to float. The power consumption increases by orders of magnitude if the pins are allowed to wally around in the linear region. If the input does not affect the logic function, then it doesn't matter what logic input state it takes. It can be tied high, low, or even to another output, as long as it is a valid logic level, so there are usually plenty of options for helping the layout out.

Comment: I just want to clarify. so you're saying I can tie the input to anything but float regardless of whether or not it affects the output?

Comment: @Mike, Tie it to Vdd or Vss. Don't tie it to Vdd/2.

Comment: Tie it to high, low, or a valid output. None of those will be vdd/2. VDD/2 is the definition of wallying around in the linear region.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  output pin 16(Vcc) to pin 15 and pin 14,13 to pin 12 ((2Y0)  so you can route between 15-14  or shift to 14-13.

Never leave floating CMOS inputs as it becomes more sensitive to stray impulse E-Field induced by nearby ESD.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would tie pin 15 (2E-) to Vcc (pin 16 adjacent) since it is active low, and tie pins 13 & 14 to GND since they are active high.

Assuming you are using a double-side board, are you routing signal traces between the pins on BOTH sides of the board?

Comment: I'm only using a single-sided board since its cheaper for me to produce circuits on them and the error rate is lower as well.